# After putting values in MainActivity it skips to MainMenu , how to make a "edit" button to return to MainActivity and edit those values again?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

After putting values in MainActivity it skips to MainMenu , how to make a "edit" button to return to MainActivity and edit those values again? I've tried to make the "edit" button and when you click it to go back to the MainActivity , but it's not happening...
Here is my MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText enterHeight, enterWeight, enterAge;

    private double height;
    private double weight;
    private double age;
    String selectedRadiobut;
    Button button;
    RadioButton radioMale, radioFemale;
    RadioGroup radioGroup;
    SharedPreferences sp;

    private boolean heightIsValid() {

        if (enterHeight.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
            enterHeight.setError("Cant be empty");
            return false;
        }

        double height = Double.valueOf(enterHeight.getText().toString());

        if (height <= 0) {

            enterHeight.setError("Cant be zero");
            return false;
        }
        if (height <= 40 || height > 250) {

            enterHeight.setError("Cant be less than 40 cm or more than 250 cm");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean weightIsValid() {
        if (enterWeight.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
            enterWeight.setError("Cant be empty");
            return false;
        }

        double weight = Double.valueOf(enterWeight.getText().toString());

        if (weight <= 0) {

            enterWeight.setError("Cant be zero");
            return false;
        }
        if (weight > 600) {

            enterWeight.setError("Cant be more than 600 kg");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean ageIsValid() {
        if (enterAge.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
            enterAge.setError("Cant be empty");
            return false;
        }

        double age = Double.valueOf(enterAge.getText().toString());

        if (age <= 0) {

            enterAge.setError("Cant be zero");
            return false;
        }
        if (age > 116) {

            enterAge.setError("Cant be older than 116 years");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean genderIsSelected() {

        if (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1) { //checking if the user has selected a option using id
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Please select gender", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            return false;
        }
        if (radioMale.isChecked()) {
            selectedRadiobut = radioMale.getText().toString();
        } else if (radioFemale.isChecked()) {
            selectedRadiobut = radioFemale.getText().toString();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
        sp = getSharedPreferences("MyUserPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        if (sp.contains("height") && sp.contains("weight") && sp.contains("age") && sp.contains("gender")) {
            // Values are stored, navigate to MainMenu directly
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainMenu.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            radioMale = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioMale);
            radioFemale = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioFemale);
            button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
            enterHeight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterHeight);
            enterWeight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterWeight);
            enterAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterAge);
            radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioSex);

            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {


                    if (heightIsValid() & weightIsValid() & ageIsValid() & genderIsSelected()) {

                        height = Double.valueOf(enterHeight.getText().toString());
                        weight = Double.valueOf(enterWeight.getText().toString());
                        age = Double.valueOf(enterAge.getText().toString());

                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
                        editor.putString("height", String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf((int) height)));
                        editor.putString("weight", String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf((int) weight)));
                        editor.putString("age", String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf((int) age)));
                        editor.putString("gender", String.valueOf(selectedRadiobut));
                        editor.commit();

                        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainMenu.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (enterHeight != null) {
            enterHeight.setText("");
        }
        if (enterWeight != null) {
            enterWeight.setText("");
        }
        if (enterAge != null) {
            enterAge.setText("");
        }
        if (radioGroup != null) {
            radioGroup.clearCheck();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my MainMenu code:

```
public class MainMenu extends AppCompatActivity { Button  btnMC , btnFN , btnRec , btnGuides, btnEdit;
    public void btnStepClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, StepCounter.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void btnCalClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MacrosCalculator.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void btnRecClick(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Recipes.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void btnEditClick(View view){
        Log.d("MainMenu", "Edit button clicked");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
        TextView age1 , height1 , weight1 , gender1;

        age1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.age1);
        height1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.height1);
        weight1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.weight1);
        gender1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gender1);
        btnMC = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMC);
        btnFN = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFN);
        btnRec = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRec);
        btnGuides = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGuides);
        btnEdit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEdit);

        SharedPreferences sp = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyUserPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String height = sp.getString("height" , "");
        String weight = sp.getString("weight" , "");
        String age = sp.getString("age" , "");
        String gender= sp.getString("gender", "");

        gender1.setText("Gender: " + gender);
        age1.setText("Age: " + age);
        height1.setText("Height(cm): " + height);
        weight1.setText("Weight(kg): " + weight);
    }
}
```

I've made a button with id = btnEdit and onClick = btnEditClick , I've made the Intent but after clicking the button it's not going to the MainActivity.

Comment: If you already entered values and saved them in SharedPreferences, in `MainActivity` this will be hit (`if (sp.contains("height") && sp.contains("weight") && sp.contains("age") && sp.contains("gender")) {`) so it just goes back to MainMenu immediately. If you want it to show those values, you have to remove that and load the values instead and put them in the various views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always set fresh new data in `onResume` of `MainActivity`:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (enterHeight != null) {
        enterHeight.setText("");
    }
    if (enterWeight != null) {
        enterWeight.setText("");
    }
    if (enterAge != null) {
        enterAge.setText("");
    }
    if (radioGroup != null) {
        radioGroup.clearCheck();
    }
}
```

This is the reason.

You need input these data as in `MainActivity` well as in `MainMenu`. (Below is just for explanation, it's not guaranteed to execute as is):

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("MyUserPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String height = sp.getString("height" , "");
    String weight = sp.getString("weight" , "");
    String age = sp.getString("age" , "");
    String gender = sp.getString("gender", "");

    enterHeight.setText(height);
    enterWeight.setText(weight);
    enterAge.setText(age);
    if (gender == "male") {
        radioGroup.check(R.id.male); // I don't know what exact R.id is.
    } else if (gender == "female") {
        radioGroup.check(R.id.female); // I don't know what exact R.id is.
    } else {
        radioGroup.clearCheck();
    }
}
```

Comment: I uploaded my code to github , can you edit there with comments for better understanding if you want and of course if you have the time for me :) Thank you in advance! Link to github: https://github.com/VGoychev/MyFitnessApp